# PHP JSON generation problems

Tags: php, html, arrays, json, php-5.6

The code below should send back an json with informations in a Database.

It takes two parameters grade and subject. The problem ist, when I use parameters are not in the database behind everything works as expected no entry, but if it would get an answer from the database nothing appears. I mean really nothing. The values i need are there i tried this and no errors are logged into the logging file. As server runs apache2 with php5.6.22 on Debian. I don't know what i did wrong. Hopefully someone can help me.

The Code:

```
case 'get_books':
    $grade = $_GET['grade'];
    $subject = $_GET['subject'];

    $sqlt = "SELECT * FROM book_type WHERE subject=".$subject." AND grade=".$grade;
    $sql = mysqli_query($db, $sqlt);
    if(!$sql){
        print(json_encode(array('response' => 2)));
        die();
    }

    $response = array();
    $response['books'] = array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        $book = array();

        $book['fullname'] = $row ["fullname"];
        $book['ISBN'] = $row ["ISBN"];
        $book['id'] = $row ["id"];

        array_push($response['books'], $book);
    }
    $response['response'] = "1";
    print(json_encode($response));
    die();
```

Comment: Did you turn on display errors or check your error logs?

Comment: *now errors are logged into the logging file* -- would help if we know what those errors were.

Comment: mistyped... i mean no

Comment: tryed echo? probably set headers?

Comment: yes i tried everything that comes in my mind

Comment: @FabianS. try implementing what I suggested, the error you received means it wasn't implemented correctly.

Comment: Your code is super dangerous!! It opens the door for SQL Injection! a very terrible attack! Use prepared statements!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be your problem:

```
array_push($response['books'], $book);
```

as far as I know you can't push a variable into a specific index of an array since no key is provided for the item being pushed.

It would be better to do this as follows:

```
case 'get_books':
$grade = $_GET['grade'];
$subject = $_GET['subject'];

$sqlt = "SELECT * FROM book_type WHERE subject=".mysqli_real_escape_string((htmlspecialchars_decode($subject, ENT_QUOTES)))." AND grade=".mysqli_real_escape_string((htmlspecialchars_decode($grade, ENT_QUOTES)));
$sql = mysqli_query($db, $sqlt);
if(!$sql){
    print(json_encode(array('response' => 2)));
    die('sql failed');
}

$response = array();
$response['books'] = array();
$response['validator'] = 'valid';
$i = 0;
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $book = array();
    $book['fullname'] = $row["fullname"];
    $book['ISBN'] = $row["ISBN"];
    $book['id'] = $row["id"];
    $response['books'][$i] = $book;
    $i++;
}
$response['response'] = "1";
var_dump($response);
//echo json_encode($response);
die();
```

Comment: This returns:

Warning: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /var/www/html/test/api/app.php on line 58

Comment: @FabianS. I didn't use array_push() in my solution, so how did you get that error?

Comment: I fixed it, but the problem is the same nothing ist printed

Comment: @FabianS. What is line 58 of /var/www/html/test/api/app.php?

Comment: i forgot commenting the array_push from before

Comment: @Jay line 58 is the `array_push()` call. I don't think he saved the file

Comment: @Jay you don't need to keep track of `$i` you can just do `$response['books'][]= $book;`

Comment: @FabianS. replace "print(json_encode($response));" with what I have done in my answer above, I made an edit. Let me know what it shows you.

Comment: @bassxzero I tried both but nothing shows up like before. And the error was my fault i frogot commenting the array_push.

Comment: This is the result of the vardump:
array(2) { ["books"]=> array(0) { } ["response"]=> string(1) "1" } {"books":[],"response":"1"}

Comment: @FabianS. okay I have made some more edits,let me know what the output is.

Comment: The result:

array(3) { ["books"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["fullname"]=> string(49) "Klett: Natura 1 - Biologie f�r Gymnasien Hs. G8" ["ISBN"]=> string(17) "978-3-12-045700-8" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" } } ["validator"]=> string(5) "valid" ["response"]=> string(1) "1" } 

the right values are there but what did you change?

Comment: @FabianS. You had spaces between your $row and your key, like this: "$row ["id"];". I changed them to not include spaces, like this: "$row["id"];"

Comment: my editor makes these spaces automaticly and they are there now again and it works

Comment: Thanks for your help and time!!

Comment: @FabianS. Only a pleasure, bro. I added some small security quirks to your original query now. :) Not bulletproof but much better than what the current query is.